# How come my object doesn't show up after rendering?

Tags: rendering

[image: before rendering]

[image: after rendering]

Basically my problem is, I can see the objects and player model perfectly fine in editing, but as soon as I render the image, the screen goes black. How can I fix this? I am new to blender so screenshots will help.

Comment: hard to tell. Could you post the [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: is your camera pointing at the model?

Comment: Do you have any lights in your scene?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information on your scene. But the fastest way to get an answer is by posting your file

Answer (score 7):

I want to tell you the answer is easy when I look at the image you posted. Your camera is facing the background and not the character. When you hit render you render what the camera sees and not the current view in the viewport. That's why you don't see anything. Select camera and press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. Your view will be moved to the camera view. Now you'll see that character is not visible. Go to the bottom panel of 3D view and press View -> Navigation -> Walk Navigation. Now use the keys <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>to move your camera around until it looks at your character, and then press <kbd>LMB</kbd>(and not <kbd>RMB</kbd> otherwise your camera will reset position). Now you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render and your character will be there.
If you still don't see it, then you need to add a lamp to your scene.

Comment: what is the WASD?

Comment: Keyboard keys - W, A, S and D. Like when you play most of games;)

Comment: walk navigation without ground?

Comment: It is in 3D view - a special feature for easy placing camera at your desired position. It has no ground data. It is for navigation not for simulations.

Comment: last time i tried it, a ground was necessary, good to know :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Align Active Camera To View" from the View>Align View menu.

[image]

(Keyboard shortcut is: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)